# Is there any way to link Google Developer and Google Cloud Services accounts?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-play-console, google-developers-console

I am using two different Google accounts for Google Developer and Google Cloud Services.   I have a live Android app and now I want enable real-time-notifications for monetisation. Is there any way that I can link my Google Developer account to Google Cloud Services Account So I can integrate Pub/Sub service?

Comment: what do you mean by Google Cloud Services account?

Comment: both Google Developer and Google Cloud Services are using different Google accounts

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly this you could use [Cloud IAM](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview) and give needed roles Developer account. So you can give ex. Project Owner rights to your Google Developer account and than this account can control the project as the owner.

But I don't think you need project owner for Pub/Sub integration. Please check [this document](https://developers.google.com/android/management/notifications) that shows such process.

As well there is possibility to merge accounts via [Google Workspace Support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en), however again I don't think this is needed to integrate pub/sub.